# Counting occurrences of a subterm in a term in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate in prolog called `occurrences(Sub, Term, N)` that will return true if `N` is the number of occurrences of `Sub` in `Term`. I'm using SWI-prolog and I found this [built-in predicate called `contains_term(Sub, Term)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/occurs.pl?public_only=false) that is true if `Sub` is contained in `Term`. So I'm trying count the number of times `contains_term` is true and make that be the `N` in the occurrences predicate.The problem is I'm not quite sure how to do this, and the fact that `contains_term` is a predefined predicate makes it harder to figure out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your linked page has an occurences_of_term predicate. Can't you use that?

Answer (score 2):

```
term_subterm_n(T, S, N) :-
   bagof(t, term_subterm(T,S), Ts),
   length(Ts, N).

term_subterm(T, T).
term_subterm(T, S) :-
   compound(T),
   T =.. [_|Es],
   member(E, Es),
   term_subterm(E, S).
```